# R script to average values every X days using different starting points

Tags: r, zoo

I have a long data set measuring height of trees once a week for 8 months. Also recorded are pot number ('pot'), the date of measuring ('date'), weeks since the start of the experiment ('no.week'), germination date ('germination'), weeks since germination ('after.germ').

I'm wanting to average tree height over 3 weeks starting at the week of germination.

For example, the experiment started on 3/25. Pot 3 germinated on 4/15 (no. week= 2). Pot 4 germinated on 4/29 (no. week= 4). I want to average the height of pot 3 starting on 4/15 and pot 4 starting on 4/29, and continue to average every 3 weeks for the duration of the experiment.

The key is starting the average at different points for each pot.

Any advice and tips would be great!

Subset:

```
    pot table germination week no.week after.germ       date height stem
61    3     2   4/15/2022   w1       1         NA  3/25/2022     NA   NA
62    3     2   4/15/2022   w2       2         NA  4/15/2022     NA   NA
63    3     2   4/15/2022   w3       3          1  4/22/2022    4.6   NA
64    3     2   4/15/2022   w4       4          2  4/29/2022   18.5   NA
65    3     2   4/15/2022   w5       5          3   5/6/2022   18.1    1
66    3     2   4/15/2022   w6       6          4  5/13/2022   18.1    1
67    3     2   4/15/2022   w7       7          5  5/20/2022   17.8    1
68    3     2   4/15/2022   w8       8          6  5/26/2022   19.4    1
69    3     2   4/15/2022   w9       9          7   6/3/2022   18.8    1
70    3     2   4/15/2022  w10      10          8  6/10/2022   19.3    1
71    3     2   4/15/2022  w11      11          9  6/17/2022   18.3    1
72    3     2   4/15/2022  w12      12         10  6/24/2022   18.6    1
73    3     2   4/15/2022  w13      13         11   7/1/2022   19.2    1
74    3     2   4/15/2022  w14      14         12   7/8/2022   19.2    1
75    3     2   4/15/2022  w15      15         13  7/15/2022   18.9    1
76    3     2   4/15/2022  w16      16         14  7/22/2022   15.3    1
77    3     2   4/15/2022  w17      17         15  7/29/2022   19.1    1
78    3     2   4/15/2022  w18      18         16   8/5/2022   19.0    1
79    3     2   4/15/2022  w19      19         17  8/12/2022   19.0    1
80    3     2   4/15/2022  w20      20         18  8/19/2022   19.8    1
81    3     2   4/15/2022  w21      21         19  8/26/2022   18.2    1
82    3     2   4/15/2022  w22      22         20   9/2/2022   19.2    1
83    3     2   4/15/2022  w24      24         21  9/16/2022   18.1    1
84    3     2   4/15/2022  w23      23         22  9/22/2022   19.2    1
85    3     2   4/15/2022  w25      25         23  9/30/2022   15.4    1
86    3     2   4/15/2022  w26      26         24  10/7/2022   18.4    1
87    3     2   4/15/2022  w27      27         25 10/14/2022   19.2    1
88    3     2   4/15/2022  w28      28         26 10/21/2022   19.0    1
89    3     2   4/15/2022  w29      29         27 10/29/2022   18.7    1
90    3     2   4/15/2022  w30      30         28  11/4/2022   19.3    1
91    6     4   4/29/2022   w1       1         NA  3/25/2022     NA   NA
92    6     4   4/29/2022   w2       2         NA  4/15/2022     NA   NA
93    6     4   4/29/2022   w3       3         NA  4/22/2022     NA   NA
94    6     4   4/29/2022   w4       4          1  4/29/2022   16.7   NA
95    6     4   4/29/2022   w5       5          2   5/6/2022   17.5    1
96    6     4   4/29/2022   w6       6          3  5/13/2022   18.8   NA
97    6     4   4/29/2022   w7       7          4  5/20/2022   18.0   NA
98    6     4   4/29/2022   w8       8          5  5/26/2022   17.2   NA
99    6     4   4/29/2022   w9       9          6   6/3/2022   17.7   NA
100   6     4   4/29/2022  w10      10          7  6/10/2022   17.9   NA
101   6     4   4/29/2022  w11      11          8  6/17/2022   18.7   NA
102   6     4   4/29/2022  w12      12          9  6/24/2022   18.1   NA
103   6     4   4/29/2022  w13      13         10   7/1/2022   17.3   NA
104   6     4   4/29/2022  w14      14         11   7/8/2022   13.8   NA
105   6     4   4/29/2022  w15      15         12  7/15/2022   18.4    1
106   6     4   4/29/2022  w16      16         13  7/22/2022   19.0    1
107   6     4   4/29/2022  w17      17         14  7/29/2022   18.8    1
108   6     4   4/29/2022  w18      18         15   8/5/2022     NA    1
109   6     4   4/29/2022  w19      19         16  8/12/2022   19.0    1
110   6     4   4/29/2022  w20      20         17  8/19/2022   19.3    1
111   6     4   4/29/2022  w21      21         18  8/26/2022   18.6    1
112   6     4   4/29/2022  w22      22         19   9/2/2022   18.2    1
113   6     4   4/29/2022  w24      24         20  9/16/2022   18.0    1
114   6     4   4/29/2022  w23      23         21  9/22/2022   18.8    1
115   6     4   4/29/2022  w25      25         22  9/30/2022   19.7    1
116   6     4   4/29/2022  w26      26         23  10/7/2022   17.4    1
117   6     4   4/29/2022  w27      27         24 10/14/2022   18.8    1
118   6     4   4/29/2022  w28      28         25 10/21/2022   19.9    1
119   6     4   4/29/2022  w29      29         26 10/29/2022   17.9    1
120   6     4   4/29/2022  w30      30         27  11/4/2022   19.5    1
211  10     2   4/29/2022   w1       1         NA  3/25/2022     NA   NA
212  10     2   4/29/2022   w2       2         NA  4/15/2022     NA   NA
213  10     2   4/29/2022   w3       3         NA  4/22/2022     NA   NA
214  10     2   4/29/2022   w4       4         NA  4/29/2022     NA   NA
215  10     2   4/29/2022   w5       5          1   5/6/2022    9.5    1
216  10     2   4/29/2022   w6       6          2  5/13/2022   15.4   NA
217  10     2   4/29/2022   w7       7          3  5/20/2022   14.3   NA
218  10     2   4/29/2022   w8       8          4  5/26/2022   15.8   NA
219  10     2   4/29/2022   w9       9          5   6/3/2022   16.1   NA
220  10     2   4/29/2022  w10      10          6  6/10/2022   16.1   NA
221  10     2   4/29/2022  w11      11          7  6/17/2022   15.9   NA
222  10     2   4/29/2022  w12      12          8  6/24/2022   16.3   NA
223  10     2   4/29/2022  w13      13          9   7/1/2022   16.2   NA
224  10     2   4/29/2022  w14      14         10   7/8/2022   16.4   NA
225  10     2   4/29/2022  w15      15         11  7/15/2022   15.7    1
226  10     2   4/29/2022  w16      16         12  7/22/2022   15.5    1
227  10     2   4/29/2022  w17      17         13  7/29/2022   15.7    1
228  10     2   4/29/2022  w18      18         14   8/5/2022   15.5    1
229  10     2   4/29/2022  w19      19         15  8/12/2022   16.0    1
230  10     2   4/29/2022  w20      20         16  8/19/2022   15.9    1
231  10     2   4/29/2022  w21      21         17  8/26/2022   15.7    1
232  10     2   4/29/2022  w22      22         18   9/2/2022   15.5    1
233  10     2   4/29/2022  w24      24         19  9/16/2022   15.1    1
234  10     2   4/29/2022  w23      23         20  9/22/2022   15.8    1
235  10     2   4/29/2022  w25      25         21  9/30/2022   15.8    1
236  10     2   4/29/2022  w26      26         22  10/7/2022   15.1    1
237  10     2   4/29/2022  w27      27         23 10/14/2022   15.9    1
238  10     2   4/29/2022  w28      28         24 10/21/2022   16.5    1
239  10     2   4/29/2022  w29      29         25 10/29/2022   15.7    1
240  10     2   4/29/2022  w30      30         26  11/4/2022   16.2    1
271  14     2   4/15/2022   w1       1         NA  3/25/2022     NA   NA
272  14     2   4/15/2022   w2       2         NA  4/15/2022     NA   NA
273  14     2   4/15/2022   w3       3          1  4/22/2022    5.8   NA
274  14     2   4/15/2022   w4       4          2  4/29/2022   19.7   NA
275  14     2   4/15/2022   w5       5          3   5/6/2022   20.1    1
276  14     2   4/15/2022   w6       6          4  5/13/2022   19.4    1
277  14     2   4/15/2022   w7       7          5  5/20/2022   20.0    1
278  14     2   4/15/2022   w8       8          6  5/26/2022   19.6    1
279  14     2   4/15/2022   w9       9          7   6/3/2022   19.6    1
280  14     2   4/15/2022  w10      10          8  6/10/2022   20.2    1
281  14     2   4/15/2022  w11      11          9  6/17/2022   21.1    1
282  14     2   4/15/2022  w12      12         10  6/24/2022   21.3    1
283  14     2   4/15/2022  w13      13         11   7/1/2022   19.4   NA
284  14     2   4/15/2022  w14      14         12   7/8/2022   20.3   NA
285  14     2   4/15/2022  w15      15         13  7/15/2022   19.5    1
286  14     2   4/15/2022  w16      16         14  7/22/2022   19.3    1
287  14     2   4/15/2022  w17      17         15  7/29/2022   22.4    1
288  14     2   4/15/2022  w18      18         16   8/5/2022   20.0    1
289  14     2   4/15/2022  w19      19         17  8/12/2022   20.0    1
290  14     2   4/15/2022  w20      20         18  8/19/2022   20.4    1
291  14     2   4/15/2022  w21      21         19  8/26/2022   19.6    1
```

I calculated the rolling average, but a rolling average isn't quite what I am looking for since I need an average over a distinct period and starting at different points.

```
library(zoo)
cg22_avg<-cg22_long %>%
            dplyr:::group_by(pot) %>%
            dplyr:::mutate('3wkavg' = rollmean(height, 3, align="right", na.pad=TRUE ))
```

Comment: Please read the information at the top of the [tag:r] tag page and in particular provide a complete minimal reproducible example including all inputs using `dput` and expected output as requested there.

Comment: The question has been edited to include a subset of the data. Thank you for the reminder.

Comment: Question needs to use `dput` and show expected output.

Comment: When I see *"once a week for 8 months"*, the first thing I notice is that your `germination` and `date` fields are strings, not `Date`-class (number-like) fields. The use of any rolling calculation will silently assume that everything is perfectly spaced day-wise. If this is ever not the case, you won't know it (from these calcs), it'll give you incorrect results silently. If you really don't care about this, then for the record note that `rollmean` is rolling on the number of observations, not on time spans.

Comment: You may want to look at the `slider` package, which aims to provide "rolling/sliding/tumbling" periods instead of unitless windows.

Comment: Good catch on the date-class! I do have a quick command to reclassify those columns into a date format before running the running average code, but I forgot to run in before posting the data here. The slider package looks like it could solve all my problems. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this use of the `slider` package will help:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(across(c(germination, date), ~ as.Date(., format = "%m/%d/%Y"))) %>%
  dplyr::filter(date >= germination) %>%
  group_by(pot) %>%
  mutate(avg3 = slider::slide_period_dbl(.x=height, .i=date, .period="week", .f=mean, .before=3)) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 103 × 10
#      pot table germination week  no.week after.germ date       height  stem  avg3
#    <int> <int> <date>      <chr>   <int>      <int> <date>      <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1     3     2 2022-04-15  w2          2         NA 2022-04-15   NA      NA  NA  
#  2     3     2 2022-04-15  w3          3          1 2022-04-22    4.6    NA  NA  
#  3     3     2 2022-04-15  w4          4          2 2022-04-29   18.5    NA  NA  
#  4     3     2 2022-04-15  w5          5          3 2022-05-06   18.1     1  NA  
#  5     3     2 2022-04-15  w6          6          4 2022-05-13   18.1     1  14.8
#  6     3     2 2022-04-15  w7          7          5 2022-05-20   17.8     1  18.1
#  7     3     2 2022-04-15  w8          8          6 2022-05-26   19.4     1  18.4
#  8     3     2 2022-04-15  w9          9          7 2022-06-03   18.8     1  18.5
#  9     3     2 2022-04-15  w10        10          8 2022-06-10   19.3     1  18.8
# 10     3     2 2022-04-15  w11        11          9 2022-06-17   18.3     1  19.0
# # … with 93 more rows
# # ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

I chose `.period="week", .before=3`, which should include all observations within exactly 3 weeks. An alternative would be `.period="day", .before=20` if you want 3 weeks but not including 3 weeks ago from today. There should be plenty of room to play here.

---

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(pot = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L,  14L, 14L, 14L), table = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), germination = c("4/15/2022", "4/15/2022",  "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022",  "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022",  "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/29/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/15/2022"), week = c("w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10", "w11", "w12", "w13", "w14",  "w15", "w16", "w17", "w18", "w19", "w20", "w21", "w22", "w24", "w23", "w25", "w26", "w27", "w28", "w29", "w30", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10", "w11", "w12", "w13", "w14", "w15", "w16", "w17", "w18", "w19", "w20", "w21", "w22", "w24", "w23", "w25", "w26", "w27", "w28", "w29", "w30", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10", "w11", "w12", "w13", "w14", "w15", "w16", "w17", "w18", "w19", "w20", "w21", "w22", "w24", "w23", "w25", "w26", "w27", "w28", "w29",  "w30", "w1", "w2", "w3", "w4", "w5", "w6", "w7", "w8", "w9", "w10", "w11", "w12", "w13", "w14", "w15", "w16", "w17", "w18", "w19", "w20", "w21"), no.week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L,  15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 24L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L), after.germ = c(NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L,  5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L), date = c("3/25/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/22/2022", "4/29/2022", "5/6/2022", "5/13/2022", "5/20/2022", "5/26/2022", "6/3/2022", "6/10/2022", "6/17/2022", "6/24/2022", "7/1/2022", "7/8/2022", "7/15/2022", "7/22/2022", "7/29/2022", "8/5/2022", "8/12/2022", "8/19/2022", "8/26/2022", "9/2/2022", "9/16/2022",  "9/22/2022", "9/30/2022", "10/7/2022", "10/14/2022", "10/21/2022", "10/29/2022", "11/4/2022", "3/25/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/22/2022", "4/29/2022", "5/6/2022", "5/13/2022", "5/20/2022", "5/26/2022", "6/3/2022", "6/10/2022", "6/17/2022", "6/24/2022", "7/1/2022", "7/8/2022", "7/15/2022", "7/22/2022", "7/29/2022", "8/5/2022", "8/12/2022", "8/19/2022", "8/26/2022", "9/2/2022", "9/16/2022", "9/22/2022", "9/30/2022", "10/7/2022", "10/14/2022", "10/21/2022", "10/29/2022", "11/4/2022", "3/25/2022", "4/15/2022",  "4/22/2022", "4/29/2022", "5/6/2022", "5/13/2022", "5/20/2022", "5/26/2022", "6/3/2022", "6/10/2022", "6/17/2022", "6/24/2022", "7/1/2022", "7/8/2022", "7/15/2022", "7/22/2022", "7/29/2022", "8/5/2022", "8/12/2022", "8/19/2022", "8/26/2022", "9/2/2022", "9/16/2022", "9/22/2022", "9/30/2022", "10/7/2022", "10/14/2022", "10/21/2022", "10/29/2022", "11/4/2022", "3/25/2022", "4/15/2022", "4/22/2022", "4/29/2022", "5/6/2022", "5/13/2022", "5/20/2022", "5/26/2022", "6/3/2022", "6/10/2022", "6/17/2022",  "6/24/2022", "7/1/2022", "7/8/2022", "7/15/2022", "7/22/2022", "7/29/2022", "8/5/2022", "8/12/2022", "8/19/2022", "8/26/2022"), height = c(NA, NA, 4.6, 18.5, 18.1, 18.1, 17.8, 19.4, 18.8, 19.3, 18.3, 18.6, 19.2, 19.2, 18.9, 15.3, 19.1, 19, 19, 19.8, 18.2, 19.2, 18.1, 19.2, 15.4, 18.4, 19.2, 19, 18.7, 19.3, NA, NA, NA, 16.7, 17.5, 18.8, 18, 17.2, 17.7, 17.9, 18.7, 18.1, 17.3, 13.8, 18.4, 19, 18.8, NA, 19, 19.3, 18.6, 18.2, 18, 18.8, 19.7, 17.4, 18.8, 19.9, 17.9, 19.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.5, 15.4, 14.3,  15.8, 16.1, 16.1, 15.9, 16.3, 16.2, 16.4, 15.7, 15.5, 15.7, 15.5, 16, 15.9, 15.7, 15.5, 15.1, 15.8, 15.8, 15.1, 15.9, 16.5, 15.7, 16.2, NA, NA, 5.8, 19.7, 20.1, 19.4, 20, 19.6, 19.6, 20.2, 21.1, 21.3, 19.4, 20.3, 19.5, 19.3, 22.4, 20, 20, 20.4, 19.6), stem = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", "103",  "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", "238", "239", "240", "271", "272", "273", "274", "275", "276", "277", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "283", "284", "285", "286", "287", "288", "289", "290", "291"))
```

Comment: This looks really great. Thank you for thinking through this! When I ran the code, I recieved an error that says "...'.i` must be in ascending order.". I tried adding an 'order' command into the script you included, but I didn't have any success

Comment: perhaps `quux %>% mutate(..) %>% arrange(date) %>% group_by(pot) %>% ...`?

Comment: That did get the script running error free- thank you! I calculated a few of the averages manually to compare against the R output and the values aren't matching up. But, I think this code will definitely help. I'll spend some time tweaking it and will update the post if I am able to get it working